# Spring Cloud Config Server in AWS Lambda

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have seen few examples of running spring boot application in AWS Lambda. Is there a way to run Spring Cloud Config Server in AWS Lambda?

Comment: what's the cloud provider do you use?

Comment: I am using AWS.

Answer (score 2):

It probably doesn't make much sense if you are using config server backed by git or svn since it uses [local disk](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/) for state in those cases. If you are using jdbc backend, it could work, though I don't know if anyone has tried.

Comment: Thanks @spencegibb. I was assuming that spring cloud config server fetches whatever property is required from git and returns back the value when it gets . a request. Does it store the values in local disk instead of fetching from git?

Comment: It does, but that means your git server needs to be as available as config server